# How to display list of video post on video section?

Tags: post-formats

I already success to display combination post between articles & video using the code below:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
          <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
            <?php if ( 'video' == get_post_format( get_the_ID() ) ) : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'template/loop', 'video' ); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'template/loop', 'post' ); ?>
            <!-- End Post -->
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          <?php else: ?>
              No post.
          <?php endif; ?>
```

But at the other section, I just want to display a video. How to do that? Please advice.

[image: This is video section that I created]

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I stuck, how to just list the video post. :)

Comment: Sorry for asking but are you familiar with coding? The answer you are looking is in your code.

Comment: Nice! If you don't mind answer your own question and accept it so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution. I'm using WP_Query as the solution. Here is the code:

```
<?php
               // The Query
                $query = new WP_Query( array( 
                      'posts_per_page' => 4,
                      'tax_query' => array(
                            array(                
                                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array('post-format-video'),
                                'operator' => 'IN')
                                )
                ) );

                if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
                        get_template_part( 'template/loop', 'video' );
                        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); else : ?>
               <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
               <?php endif; ?>
```

So, it will only appear the video post format. :)